iOS 17 UIImageReader cause memory leak
In my SwiftUI view, I try to load the image from the data.
var body: some View {
        Group{
            if let data = model.detailImageData, let uiimage = UIImage(data: data) {// no memory issue
                Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
   }

But I want to get the HDR style of my image, so I use
if let data = model.detailImageData, let uiimage = UIImageReader.default.image(data:data){ //memory leaks!!!

When I change the data, the memory of the previous image is never freeed. finally caused my app to crash. You can see it from the Instrument screenshot.

